# Creating sessions in ASP.NET MVC C# like PHP Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I am having a problem with redirecting from page to page in my ASP.NET MVC application.

Currently, login functionality does not have a problem. The expected output after logging in was to redirect to the home page of the application.

Inside the home page, there is a logout button to destroy the session that has been created after logging in and redirect to login page.

But after destroying the session, and try to put this on the address bar of the browser `https://localhost:44360/home/home` which is the home page of the application. It was redirected even though there is no account logged in. Also, even after logging out to an account, if you click the back button of the browser, the home page is shown that it shouldn't be.

In PHP, after logging in, the session is created and you only need to call that Session to check if there is a user, if not, then it will redirect you to a 404 Error Page Not Found Or if you type only the link inside the address bar of the browser and there is no session created it will also redirect you to an error page. I want to implement this kind of session in my ASP.NET MVC application, but how?

Here is my code:

**LoginController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel userInfo, FormCollection collection, string returnUrl)
{
    ILogicInterface<LogicalUserInput, LogicalSystemResult> iLogic = new UserLoginCheck();
    LogicalUserInput userInput = new LogicalUserInput();
    _ = new LogicalSystemResult();

    try
    {
        userInput[typeof(LoginModel).FullName] = userInfo;
        LogicalSystemResult systemResult = iLogic.DoProcess(userInput);
        bool userCheckExist = systemResult.ResultCode != LogicalSystemResult.RESULT_CODE_ERR_DATA_NOT_EXIST;

        if (userCheckExist)
        {
            UserLoginModel loginModel = systemResult[typeof(UserLoginModel).FullName] as UserLoginModel;
            Session["userInfo"] = loginModel;
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginModel.email, true);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                if (loginModel.AccountType == 0) 
                {
                     return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
                } 
                else 
                {
                     return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error");
                }                   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TempData.Clear();
            TempData["Title"] = "Error!";
            TempData["Message"] = " Invalid Username Or Password.";
            return View();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error");
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
// GET: Home
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Home()
{
    if (Session["userInfo"] == null) 
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error");
    } 
    else 
    {
        UserLoginModel userLoginModel = Session["userInfo"] as UserLoginModel;
        TempData["user"] = userLoginModel.lastName + ", " + userLoginModel.firstName + " " + userLoginModel.middleName;
        string cookieValue = GlobalFunctions.StringToBase64Encode(userLoginModel.email);
        HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie(GlobalFunctions.StringToBase64Encode("userInformation"), cookieValue);
        newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);

        return View();              
    }         
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOut() 
{
    try 
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    
        Session["userInfo"] = null;
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is how I call the `LogOut` function inside the home controller in my `Home.cshtml`.

```
<script>
    $("#cmdLogOff").on("click", function () {
        $("#HomeView").submit();
    });
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("LogOut",
         null,
         new AjaxOptions
         {
         },
    new { id = "HomeView" }))
{
   
}
```

Thank you and Regards,

Comment: Are you sure the LogOut action is being executed? A form's default method is "GET" and you aren't specifying it as "POST" on the AjaxOptions, but your LogOut method is tagged as "[HttpPost]"...

Comment: @Gusman , yes. the logout function was triggered after logging out to an account.

Answer (score 0):

many framework in php use SESSOIN for identity
flush session and you will see automatic logout
but dotnet use cookie instead session in identity